# iOS Scroll Bars not visible on Tab Bar

Tags: ios, tabs, scrollbar, uitabbar

I have an app with a tab bar. One of the tabs is a menu with scroll bars. When I navigate to this view the first time, the scroll bars are visible. After I navigate away to another tab, then back to the menu, the scroll bars are no longer visible when a user scrolls.

Is there a reason this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy scrollbar code from `viewDidLoad` method and paste into `viewWillAppear` method. This will work whenever you open the tab.

`viewDidLoad` - Works one time only

`viewWillAppear` - works whenever you open the `UIViewcontroller`